# Weird Control+C behaviour

Tags: linux, bash, debian

So logged into vm via ssh, started vim, suspended the process via ctrl+z and then spammed ctrl+c a couple of times. Apparently after the 10th time or so it kills vim. Why?

Doesn't happen in PuTTy no idea why.

Picture:

[image]

Comment: Note that Ctrl-C sends a SIGINT to the foreground process, not a SIGTERM. So something else may be at play here. Are you able to replicate this on other machines, or with other background processes?

Comment: @dimo414 Yeah i dont really get it. Not happening when using PuTTy. Same Debian Version (8.7). On my VM if i suspend nano/less for example ctrl+c kills it instantly, which shouldnt happen right? Since  ctrl+c is only suppose to kill processes in the foreground right? No Idea why vim even survives so long lol.